# Is there any way to use MSMF on win11?

Tags: python, opencv, video-capture

i used the following code to use my camera but instead, it showed a warning

```
import cv2, time

video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  #here is the problem

time.sleep(3)

video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

it shows the following error

`` [ WARN:0] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (438) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback ``

searching on the internet, i came to know that it is because i am using outdated windows and i should rather try
`cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)` instead of `cv2.VideoCapture(0)`
this solves the problem but I am currently using win11 and having so low fps might not be suitable, any alternatives?

Comment: it's "just a warning" but I'm sure `assert video.isOpened()` will fail. it's complaining that it can't open *that* index. try a different index, though if there is a camera at all, it should be at index 0. -- no, it's not "outdated windows". DSHOW has been around longer but MSMF isn't that new either. it's just that the MSMF code in OpenCV behaves differently from the DSHOW code... or let's say it warns about things a lot more than the DSHOW code does.

Comment: if you don't get the FPS you expect, try setting CAP_PROP_FOURCC to `MJPG`. that works for some webcams. MJPG is lossy compression but needs less data rate. USB 2 is "fast" but not so fast that high resolution video can just flow at full frame rate *without compression*.

Comment: Hi, @ChristophRackwitz , i know that it's a warning but the program won't execute until i use 'DSHOW' and they warning pops in the terminal without turning on my camera

Answer (score 0):

I get problems when running, cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW) I get NoneType for frame. This did work for me before. I now use this,

```
import cv2
import time

#set backend to DSHOW
cv2.CAP_DSHOW

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
time.sleep(3)
cap.release()
```